# spring security core plugin - invalidate a user session

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-4

I am using grails 4.0.3 and I am trying to logout a user programmatically. I search for this but all the solutions that I found are for grails 2 and are not working for grails 4.

Like - [force logout for authenticated user using spring security plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051887/force-logout-for-authenticated-user-using-spring-security-plugin)

Does anyone have any idea how to invalidate a user session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have any idea how to invalidate a user session?

In a controller you can invoke `session.invalidate()`.

If you want to access the session from some other context, you could have that class implement the `grails.web.api.ServletAttributes` trait, which will provide the `session` property to that class and then `session.invalidate()` may be called from there.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's solution works for the current user's session only. If you want to logout/invalidate all the sessions (or all the sessions of a particular user) then you can use this solution.

Make a custom session listener class-

```
class MyCustomSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
  Map<String, HttpSession> sessions = [:].asSynchronized()

  void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    sessions.put(se.session.id, se.session)
  }

  void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    sessions.remove(se.session.id)
  }

  void invalidateAllSessionsOfUser(String username) {
    List<HttpSession> sessionsList = []
    sessions.each { sessionId, sess ->
      SecurityContext sc = sess[SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY]
      if (sc.authentication.principal.username == username) {
        sessionsList.add(sess)
      }
    }
    sessionsList*.invalidate()
  }
  
  void invalidateAllSessions() {
    List<HttpSession> sessionsList = []
    sessions.each { sessionId, sess ->
      sessionsList.add(sess)
    }
    sessionsList*.invalidate()
  }
}
```

and make an entry in `resources.groovy`

```
beans = {
  myCustomSessionListener(MyCustomSessionListener)
}
```